How to save the fragments or load them in advance so that when navigating through navController.navigate() from BottomNavigationView
1 problem. How to save fragments or load them in advance, so that when navigating through navController.navigate() from BottomNavigationView they will be saved somehow.
2 problem. Why data is not passed through onOrderPass. It is not called at all
With ViewPager it was fast, and no problems, but I had to switch to Jetpack Navigation as it would be more appropriate here
Below is the main activity:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope by MainScope() {
    //Variables

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        b = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        makeNavigation()
        makeViewModel()
        setSupportActionBar(b.appToolBar)
        setContentView(b.root)
   
        b.byDataEditedView.setOnClickListener {
            chooseSimpleFilter("date_edited")
        }
        b.byDataAddedView.setOnClickListener {
            chooseSimpleFilter("date_added")
        }
        b.byTitleView.setOnClickListener {
            chooseSimpleFilter("title")
        }
        b.byDescBodyView.setOnClickListener {
            chooseSimpleFilter("body")
        }
        b.byColorCodeView.setOnClickListener {
            chooseSimpleFilter("color_code")
        }

    }

    private fun makeNavigation() {
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController
        b.navigation.selectedItemId = R.id.homeFragment
        b.navigation.setOnItemSelectedListener { id ->
            //Some logic for get a filter
            changePageSimpleFilter(filter)
            return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
        }
        b.navigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    private fun makeViewModel() {
        val noteRepository = NoteRepository(LifeDataBase(this))
        val viewModelProviderFactory = NoteViewModelProviderFactory(application, noteRepository)
        noteViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
            this, viewModelProviderFactory
        )[NoteViewModel::class.java]
    }

    private fun showFilter(simpleFilter: Boolean) {
        if (simpleFilter) {
            b.advancedFilter.visibility = View.GONE
            b.simpleFilter.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            b.advancedFilter.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            b.simpleFilter.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    private fun changePageSimpleFilter(filter: String) {
        //Some logic
        orderPass(filter)
    }

    private fun chooseSimpleFilter(filter: String) {
        //Some logic
        orderPass(filter)
    }

    private fun orderPass(filter: String) {
        orderPass?.onOrderPassNote(filter)
    }

    fun setOnOrderPassListener(listener: OrderPass) {
        orderPass = listener
    }
}

Below is one of the fragments that takes about 4 seconds to load when navigating to it.
class NotesFragment: Fragment(), NoteClick, OrderPass, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    private lateinit var b: FragmentNotesBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: NoteViewModel
    private lateinit var mAdapter: NoteAdapter
    private lateinit var prevTextView: TextView
    private lateinit var intent: Intent
    private var query: String? = null
    private var displayType: DisplayType? = null
    private var colorId: Int? = null
    private var order: String? = null
    private var dayOfWeekS: String? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        b = FragmentNotesBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        return b.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = (activity as MainActivity).noteViewModel
        setUpRecyclerView()
        setToolbar()
        //A little logic, not important
        (activity as MainActivity).setOnOrderPassListener(this)
    }

    private fun setUpRecyclerView() {
        mAdapter = NoteAdapter(this)
        b.recyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            adapter = mAdapter
        }
    }

    private fun setToolbar() {
        val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()
        menuHost.addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
            override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)
                val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_item)
                val mMenuSearch = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
                mMenuSearch.isSubmitButtonEnabled = false
                mMenuSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(this@NotesFragment)
            }
            override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        }, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
    }

    private fun updateViewModel() {
        val sortQuery = """SELECT * FROM NOTES WHERE
          (:query IS NULL OR title LIKE :query OR body LIKE :query) 
              ORDER BY $order"""
        viewModel.getNotes(SimpleSQLiteQuery(
            sortQuery,
            arrayOf(query)
        )).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { notes ->
            mAdapter.differ.submitList(notes)
        }
    }

    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
        query = "%$newText%"
        if (query == "%%") query = null
        updateViewModel()
        return true
    }

    override fun onOrderPassNote(data: String) {
        order = data
        updateViewModel()
    }
}

For some reason I have not found an answer that satisfies me, I'm sure there are solutions, but I probably didn't understand it or didn't search well enough, even though it took a long time
